# Stationary wrapfigure forced to float

Tags: wrapfigure

I have been using the wrapfigure for quite some time now and today, the following problem occured: My figure is floating instead of text being wrapped around it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Durchgearbeitete Beispiele}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw[step=0.5,very thin,color=lightgray](17,11)grid(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\setlist[1]{itemsep=-3pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\end{itemize}
\underline{Vorgehen}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example isn't really [minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: From the manual *You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or immediately
before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a list if there is a blank line
(\par) in between.*

Comment: Anyway what is the meaning of `wrapping ` a figure that is `0.8\textwidth` wide? It should be displayed in its own zone of the page.

Comment: @Bernard I will eventually make the figure a bit smaller as the task is not to exceed two pages and some more information needs to be added.

Comment: @HenriMenke I guess it isn't... I'll make it better next time.

Comment: @Jurg: Oh, btw, if you can't use `wrapfigure` in the neighbourhood of a list environment, you should be able to use it in the neighbourhood of an environment that only `emulates`a list — I'm thinking of the `listliketab` package.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your reply as well. I tried it, it created my list-'lookalike', but it didn't work in the neighbourhood of the wrapfigure-environment either.